# Can't get execvp to execute file

Tags: c

I am trying to write a program that will fork, then open a file and execute it. The file it should execute is called child and it has been compiled. When I type ./child, it runs. However, when I run this program it does not execute the child program and I am prompted with the error message I put in "Execution failed". What I am doing wrong?

This is my parent class

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>



int main (int argc, char **argv)
{ 

pid_t parent = getpid();
pid_t pid = fork();


if (pid == -1)
{
// error, failed to fork()
} 
else if (pid > 0)
{
int status;
 waitpid(pid, &status, 0);
}
else 
{

int var = execvp("./child", NULL);

if(var < 0)
{
    printf("Execution failed");
}

}
exit(0);   // exec never returns
}
```

This is the child

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


int main (int argc, char **argv)
{   
printf ("Im the child");
exit (0);
}
```

Comment: 1. Read the documentation carefully. 2. Print out `errno` and if possible `strerror(errno)`, what does it say? 3. Why do you think `./child` should be passed to `execvp()`? 3. What should the second paramter be? 4. Did you read the documentation? I don't think you did, because you would know what the 2nd parameter should be. Don't take bad, but please read the documentation before asking.

Comment: It can be improvable (a lot of warnings by the compiler for the main...), but for me the code works.

Comment: Can you think of any reason why it doesn't work for me? The child program never executes.

Comment: But... is `child` in the same directory of the `main` executable (the one that forks)?

Comment: It is very unlikely that the 'code works'.  the parameters to `execvp()` are not correct.

Comment: the function: `execvp()` does not return unless there is an error.  So no need to be checking the returned value.  infact, after the call there should be exactly two statements. `perror( "execvp failed" );  exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`

Comment: the function: `getpid()`  and the definition for `pid_t` are in the header file: `unistd.h`  which your code fails to include

Comment: it is a very poor programming practice to `#include` header files those contents are not used.  Both the posted programs have: `#include <string.h>`  but nothing is used from the header file

Comment: When the parameters from `main()` are not used, then the signature should be: `int main( void )`

Comment: regarding: `printf ("Im the child");` the stream: `stdout` is buffered, so nothing is actually displayed on the users' terminal until either: 1) an input statement is executed, 2) the buffer overflows 3) the statement `fflush( stdout );` is executed or 4)  a newline sequence is output or 5) the program exits. In this case, appending `\n` to the end of the format string will fix the problem.

Comment: regarding: `printf("Execution failed");` 1) see my prior comment about stdout being buffered 2) error messages should be output to `stderr`, not `stdout` Suggest using: `perror( "Execution failed" );`  which will output the enclosed text and the matching text. selected by the current value of `errno`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually don't know what you are doing wrong. After a copy and a compilation (and several warning complains) your code runs fine (GCC 7.2).

Obviously, child must be in the same working directory in which you run your main executable (the one that forks).

But probably I would write that code in this way, but I'm not an expert in forking:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <errno.h>

extern int errno;

int main () {
  pid_t pid = fork();

  if (pid < 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", strerror(errno));
    return 1;
  }

  if (pid == 0) {
   int ret = execl("./child", "", (char *)NULL);
   if(ret < 0) {
     fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", strerror(errno));
     return 1;
   }
  } else {
    wait(NULL);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

At least it tells you which error `execl` has encountered.